# Computed Property

Tags: swift, computed-properties

I have this code and there is a problem in it
I need to determain the colour name based on the value of the red , the green and the blue value using structure and computed properties.

```
struct Colour {
  var red:Int
  var green:Int
  var blue:Int
  var colourName: String
  var chosenColour: String {
    return "The colour is \(colourName)"
  }
}
 
var colour = Colour(red:255 , green:255 , blue:255, 

colourName:"White" )
print(colour.chosenColour)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your approach has a major flaw: there's two sources of truth for the colour (one for its RGB components, and one for its name). What if the two conflict? E.g. what if I write `Colour(red:0 , green:0 , blue:0 , colourName: "pink")`? You should use the RGB component values to *derive* a name, rather than asking the user to provide the name redundantly to the component values.

Comment: Do not use 8 bits per color channel anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A computed property calculates its value depending on other values (in the object).

An efficient solution is a `switch` statement

```
struct Colour {
    var red: Int
    var green: Int
    var blue: Int
    var colourName: String
    var chosenColour: String {
        switch (red, green, blue) {
            case (255, 255, 255): return "White"
            case (0, 0, 0): return "Black"
            case (255, 0, 0): return "Red"
            case (0, 255, 0): return "Green"
            case (0, 0, 255): return "Blue"
            default: return "Mixed Colour"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution to the problem. (Voted)

Comment: Although what is the point of having separate properties `colourName` and `chosenColour`? It would make more sense to have `colourName` be the computed color name property, have `chosenColour` be a second computed property that would return a descriptive sentence describing the color.